# PHP Timezone Conversion from "IST GMT+5:30" to something like Asia/Kolkata

Tags: php, date, timezone

I'm having one string like "IST GMT+5:30" and I want to convert it into something like 'Asia/Kolkata' or any Indian Time Zone.

What I was trying is

```
$userSubmittedTimezoneString='IST';
$userTimezone = new DateTimeZone($userSubmittedTimezoneString);
print_r($userTimezone);
```

When  $userSubmittedTimezoneString='IST', it gives following output :

```
DateTimeZone Object ( [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Jerusalem )
```

'Asia/Jerusalem' is a **Israel Time Zone** but what i want is **India Standard Time**.

Please help me to achieve this using php.

**EDIT :**

"IST GMT+5:30" is dynamic. It comes from database.

Comment: I don't know whether there's a unique solution particularly for India, but in general this is hardly possible. There may be any number of concrete timezones which map to the same GMT offset, even given a country limit.

Comment: @deceze : Actually "IST GMT+5:30" can be anything similar to timezone, similar but not exact same, that's the issue.

Comment: @ParagTyagi : where is the answer?

Comment: So there's basically no solution. You can't uniquely convert a GMT offset to a timezone. Maybe only some short form like "IST" *could* be converted. What possible inputs could you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because timezone abbreviations are not unique, and neither are timezone offsets, there is no solution that is completely robust and guaranteed to work in all scenarios**.

For instance, in this scenario, the timezones `Asia/Colombo` and `Asia/Kolkata` would match your offset and abbreviation. Other scenarios are much worse; for instance `CET +01:00` covers over 50 timezone identifiers across Europe and Africa.

If you don't know what datetime your abbreviation and offset was referring to, then you've got another problem: DST. For instance, you'd only be able to match `BST +01:00` if you knew that it applied to a date in British Summer Time.

However, if you accept the above issues, then you can have a guess at the timezone:

```
function findTimezone($offset, $date = 'now', $countries = \DateTimeZone::ALL) {
    foreach (\DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers($countries) as $timezone) {
        $datetime = new \DateTime($date, new \DateTimeZone($timezone));

        // find a timezone matching the offset and abbreviation
        if ($offset == $datetime->format('T P')) {
            return $timezone;
        }
    }
}

var_dump(findTimezone('IST +05:30', '2014-04-22 00:00:00'));
```

This returns the first timezone that matches the given abbreviation and offset.

If you haven't stored the datetime with the offset, then the above may give the correct result in some cases, but you might need to try more than one date before you found a match (e.g. 1 January and 1 July).

In summary: no such "conversion" exists, but an educated guess is certainly possible, given a number of caveats.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,  this is quite satisfactory answer. +1 for this answer :)